# input rows of a column

Tags: css, r, for-loop, if-statement

I've have a data frame (df) in which there is a column g which has the below data

```
g
 1         check
 2    2267631926
 3          <NA>
 4         check
 5         check
 6         check
 7         check
 8         check
 9         check
10         check
11         check
12         check
13         check
14         check
15         check
16         check
17         check
18         check
19    2090125960
20          <NA>
21         check
22         check
```

I'm trying to input only the numeric values (2090125960) in into a web link and jump the others (check, NA) using the css selectors one by one and follow next commands but, it is pasting the complete list.

```
` for(i in g)
  {

 mybrowser$navigate("https://www.google.com")

fg<- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector',"#lst-ib")
fg$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
fg$sendKeysToElement(i)

Go<- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector',"#tsf > div.tsf-p > div.jsb > center > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(1)")
Go$clickElement()

}`
```

Now I'm trying to enter the numeric value (one at a time) in the google search bar and hit on search then take the second value and click on search. I think this should clear my doubt.

I tried to convert the columns into factor or numeric. Any ideas would help. Thank you.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you want to accomplish. You could just make a vector containing all the numerical values from `g` and use this new vector in your loop. For example: `g<-as.numeric(g)
g<-g[!is.na(g)]`

Comment: @Mr. Zen, thank you it gave the required numeric data. I made it a dataframe and used in the loop but I get the error 
      `Selenium message:java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: java.lang.ClassCastException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
>  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching your for loop to the following format.

```
g <- df[!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(df$g))),]

for(i in g)
  {
    mybrowser$navigate("https://somelink")

    fg<- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector',"cssselector")
    fg$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(1)

    fg$sendKeysToElement(list(as.character(i)))

    Go<- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector',"#SubmitButton_button")
    Go$clickElement()

}
```

Comment: The main change is in the line `fg$sendKeysToElement(i)` previously you had this line saying `fg$sendKeysToElement(df$g)` which would provide the entire column from `df$g` instead of the current item being processed `i`.

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but it doesn't paste anything and gives an error
  `Selenium message:java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.List

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: java.lang.ClassCastException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method`

Comment: It appears as though the sendKeysToElement function requires the input to be in list format. I've updated my answer to show the new format, and also changed the data type of i to be character before applying it to the sendkey function.